# Generic lookup function as parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to clean duplicate code. The only difference are calls like

```
MyType x = Foo.LookupService<MyType>();
```

vs.

```
MyType x = Bar.FindService<MyType>();
```

So we have two methods of type `T xxx<T>()`, i.e. a method returning an instance of `T` given the class parameter `T`. How could I pass such functions as a parameter to a method that tries to find instances of different types, something like

```
foo([magic generics stuff] resolve)
{
     MyType x = resolve<MyType>();
     MyOtherType y = resolve<MyOtherType>();
}
```

Comment: Your code basically just shows calling to different Methods. What are you trying to achieve. Maybe you should show the original code as Well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your updated question, I'd have to say it looks like what you'll need to do is accept a parameter that implements an interface--something like `IResolver`, perhaps--which in turn provides a generic `Resolve<T>` method:

```
public interface IResolver
{
    T Resolve<T>();
}

void foo(IResolver resolver)
{
    MyType x = resolver.Resolve<MyType>();
    MyOtherType y = resolver.Resolve<MyOtherType>();
}
```

The reason for this is that you cannot (as far as I know) pass a generic delegate as a parameter to a non-generic method. What I mean is, you cannot have this:

```
void foo(Func<T> resolve)
{
}
```

When `T` is a type parameter, it has to be established *within the declaration*, not within the parameters themselves. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm not sure what good this accomplishes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me realize my question was not specific enough.

Comment: @Christoph: I think I understand your intentions a little better now (though **real** code would always be more helpful). Take a look at my revised answer and see if it makes sense to you.

Comment: The information that it's not possible to pass a generic parameter to a non-generic method was the relevant information for me. Hence, your solution with an interface seems to be the optimal solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`[magic generics stuff]` = [`Func<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it showed me that my question was too unspecific. I edited it.